# Nginx if cookie exists set expires

Tags: nginx

In the nginx default config file how can i set different "expires" time in the header whether a specific cookie name exists or not. I tried with if but it doesn't work as it's "ifevil".
This is what i tried: it's always evaluated to 0 whether that cookie exists or not.

```
set $expiry 60m;
if ($http_cookie ~ "cookie_name") {
   set $expiry   0s;
}

location ... {
   expires   $expiry;
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `$http_cookie`

Comment: You may use nginx.org/r/map to set the value of the variable "expiry" based on the value of a cookie.

Comment: you sir just saved the day.. it was a typo as you spotted, i can't believe i spent half a day on this... thanks a lot